# Spacing that changes by line breaks

Tags: html

So I have some code in HTML that changes by whitespace.
My CSS:

```
span{height:200px;width:200px;border-width:1px;border-color:black;border-style:solid;display:inline-block}
```

My HTML:

Before:

```
<span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span>
```

After:

```
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
```

The second is much easier to read, but the display changes and the display I desire is the first ones display, but editing is much easier with the second. Any ideas?

Comment: What sort of answer are you looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Span`s are `display: inline-block` by default, which unfortunately means they do get affected by whitespace. One solution is to just not use whitespace between them, which is easier done especially if your HTML is produced by a preprocessor like PHP … Another way is this:

```
<span></span><!--
--><span></span><!--
--><span></span><!--
--><span></span>
```

etc. Even though it's still somewhat ugly, you get no whitespace between the `span`s, while still having them on separate lines.

And yet another way would be to change the CSS for the `span`s, making them `display: block` and `float: left`, for example, but that might not work in your case.

Answer (score 0):

This HTML isn't different, you are probably editing in a modified HTML editor which takes linebreaks into account. If so, there isn't anyway to get the first output from the second HTML.